# Detect image resolution?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I've made some research and couldn't find the answer. Is it possible to detect an image resolution using an upload file field?

Right now, I can detect the size of an image in pixels...But I would need it to find the "inches" size.
And I also need to find out the resolution of the image.

Using Javascript would be the best...if possible, if not...PHP maybe?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand, resolution is the pixel count no?

Comment: @Erik: +1. Resolution is a ratio between real dimensions (if printed somewhere, in cm/inch/...) and pixels number. So it doesn't make sense to speak of resolution here.

Comment: Well, You can have a 800px X 600px at 300dpi, and 72 dpi too. but you are right. Sorry my question wasn't clear. I can calculate the size in pixels right now, but I would need it to determine the size in inches and the resolution of the image

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to do this once it has been submitted. Check out the getimagesize function in PHP - http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php

Comment: How come I can detect the size using Javascript without submitting anything? Ex : http://jsfiddle.net/VGgjz/1/

Answer (score 1):

You will need a browser that supports the [`FileReader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/FileReader) interface - read more at [Is it possible to get info from a file on the client side without uploading the file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11750542/1048572).

There are some javascript libraries reading such information like EXIF from the file:

- [JsJpegMeta](http://code.google.com/p/jsjpegmeta/)
- [ImageInfo](http://blog.nihilogic.dk/2008/08/imageinfo-reading-image-metadata-with.html) - although I'm not sure whether it gets its binary data by ajax from already uploaded files.

If you want to offer this functionality to user with browsers not supporting this, you will need to upload the file and do it serverside (with PHP).