# Rails: Get file attributes without uploading a file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, file-upload

I am currently using the gem dragonfly (been thinking of changing as this might not be what I actually need).
I have been using it to get information about files by dragging and dropping them into the upload button location.

However, all I really want to do is analyse the file properties instead of actually uploading it to my application. (Attributes like; filename, folder location, file size and modified date)

I have been able to get some variables but I haven't been able to get the modified date of the file on my machine, instead it's getting the modified date of the file I upload (which again, I don't really need or want to upload an actual file).

Currently I have been trying to use:

```
File.stat("testfile").mtime
```

However, I have been unsuccessful in attempting to use this with `params[:files]`. I have also tried to use `params[:files].path` but it isn't available for use in the same way that `File.stat(@files.path).mtime` is (again, this will result in giving me the time at which I uploaded the file(s) to my application rather than of the files themselves...

Is there a way to get the attributes of a file without uploading it? And in turn get the attributes of the file on my machine rather than the one I upload?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I haven't had the opportunity to work with dragonfly, but I'm going to infer that, if you just want to check out the metadata of a file *without* uploading, you may not be well served by a back-end library due to its nature.

Rails runs on the server, so all the operations it does are done on the server side. You need to send the file to the server for it to be understood by rails. Which is, you know, a perfectly valid way to do things but may effectively end up not being what you want.

Can you try javascript to read the file, then send your metadata to your rails server? Check out this answer.

[Is it possible to get info from a file on the client side without uploading the file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11750542/is-it-possible-to-get-info-from-a-file-on-the-client-side-without-uploading-the)

Comment: Thank you for your response, I will look into this.

I was also thinking about using dropzone.